# How to force a compile time function's argument to be of a specific type in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

Is there a way to force setting compile type of a function argument to an expected type defined in a function's signature when we only known that object type is `Any`? Let me demonstrate it with a simple example.

Given that we have defined the following three functions:

```
def writeInt(value: Int): Unit { ... }

def writeString(value: String): Unit { ... }

def get(name: String): Any = { ... }
```

How could I make the following code compile successfully without forcing a programmer referencing `writeInt` function in his program to explicitly state that what `get` returns should be used `.asInstanceOf[Int]`:

```
writeInt(get("dividend").asInstanceOf[Int]) // this works...
writeInt(get("dividend"))                   // but this does not :(
```

Since `get` may return `Any` object, which may be an `Int` as well as a `String`, is there an elegant way to solve it in *Scala* without an ugly `.asInstanceOf[Int]` notation?

Please note that in some other part of a program, I would like to be able to respectively write this code using the same functions without needing to type `.asInstanceOf[String]` again:

```
writeString(get("name").asInstanceOf[String]) // this works...
writeString(get("name"))                      // but this does not :(
```

Essentially, I know that `get("dividend")` returns an `Int` while `get("name")` returns a `String`. But how can I let compiler know it without too much clutter?

Comment: I think the short answer is "no". If your return type is Any then there is no way for the compiler to know.

Comment: One idea is to have your getter to work with a type rather than a string `def get[Name]: String ... def get[Id]: Long`. Where Name and Id here are custom types you created.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting idea, however it will not work for my use case. A string cannot be replaced with a type, because it is going to be an arbitrary string coming from the outside world. It could literally be anything.

Comment: then in this case, it will really hard to know the types at compile time. get("a") could be a String, whereas get("b") could be a Long. I also assume that arbitrary data can also be stored at runtime?

Comment: Well, the thing is that it is not hard to know the types at a compile time, because I already know them at a compile time (long story short: I have this information stored in a HashMap that holds class name and actual value for each key), so there are no ambiguities here. That means I know that get("a") IS a String, whereas get("b") IS a Long, and I have this information already at hand at a compile time. The question is, how can I access it in a generic way in the code that defines "def get(name: String)" method without a need to explicitly call "asInstanceOf" on its result.

Answer (score 2):

You might go with a wrapper for your `write` methods.

```
def writeAny(a: Any): Unit = a match {
  case s: String => writeString(s)
  case i: Int    => writeInt(i)
}
```

A better solution would have your `get()` method return `Either[String,Int]`.  Then your code could do something like this:

```
get(str).fold(writeString, writeInt)
```

As a general rule, `Any` should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: These "write" methods are given here only as examples. They are not "mine" as you call them, thus I cannot really modify them. You may replace them with any built-in or custom method you can think of in your reasoning, e.g. "def substring(int beginIndex)" or "def startsWith(String prefix)" if that helps. The only part that is within my control is a definition of "def get(name: String)" method. I am wondering if there exists a way of parameterising it some way that allows me not to cast its return type, but somehow infer it from its "name" argument, e.g. I know that "dividend" is always "Int".

Comment: I only used the term "your" in the informal sense that _you_ chose to bring them to our attention by using them as examples, and _your_ question is about how to work with them. As a general rule, the compiler sees types, not values. So, outside of writing a macro for this purpose, the compiler can't make type decisions based on something that could, in some circumstances, be a result of user input.